# Do points $A$, $C$ and $Y$ determine a plane?

Tags: geometry

The postulate "Through any three noncollinear points, there exists exactly one plane." tells me that the answer to the question is YES. But those points are not coplanar based on the given diagram. That makes me confused. What do you think?

Here's the diagram:
[image]

Comment: In that diagram, it looks as if $A$, $D$, and $Y$ all belong to $\mathcal R$.

Comment: The correct postulate needs to mention that the three points are not colinear for the plane to be unique

Comment: @Vsotvep oh sure. sorry.I already corrected it. thanks. points $A$, $C$ and $Y$ are noncollinear, so does that mean they determine a plane?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes those points are coplanar. but the question is $A$, $C$ and $Y$.

Comment: Just because A, C and Y aren't all on the planes already drawn doesn't mean they're not coplanar - three points in R^3 will *always* be coplanar.

Comment: @harpey1111 That's what I wrote, right? I mean; $A$, $C$, and $Y$.

Comment: If they are also coplanar, then they determine a plane, right? In elementary geometry, following the postulates and theorems, will they be coplanar, meaning they determine a plane?

Comment: @ConMan Do you really think that I don't know that?

Comment: @harpey1111 Yes, since they are not collinear.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so I can say that as long as three points are not collinear, whether in 2D or 3D, they determine a plane, right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I will post that as an answer.

Comment: @harpey1111 in 2D, there is only one plane, namely the whole space, so trivially any points in 2D are coplanar.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was addressing the OP, who seemed to be claiming that A, C and Y are not coplanar.

Comment: @ConMan Got it. Thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

Given any three points in $\mathbb R^3$, there is always a plane passing through them. That plane is unique if and only if the three points are not collinear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture of the plane through $A$, $C$ and $Y$:

[image]